# PHP form, converting input field into a drop down list

Tags: php, html

The below code is a simple form that is sending the data that is inputted to my local database.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Insert data into database using mysqli</h1>
            <div id="login">
                <h2>Student's Form</h2>
                <hr/>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label>Student Name  :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="stu_name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
                    <label>Student Email  :</label>
                    <input type="email" name="stu_email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="john123@gmail.com"/><br/><br />
                    <label>Student City  :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="stu_city" id="school"   required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Your City"/><br/><br />
                    <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
                </form>
            </div>

        <!-- Right side div -->

        </div>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "Student";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_school)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["stu_name"]."','".$_POST["stu_email"]."','".$_POST["stu_city"]."')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
            } else {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue that I am finding is that I am trying to change the Student City input field into a drop down where the values is retrieve from the database and put into a drop down list for a new user to select.

Could someone advise on what needs to be done please.

i am trying to use the below code and send the below list to my database.

```
       <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
```

but i am finding it hard to send the these values to the database with my above code as well as where to place this code.

Comment: Minor question: do you have a separate table for cities? From the above sql I would guess that the db is not normalised and that you store the city name in `students` table rather than an id that references a separate table?
Also, instead of a dropdown menu you could opt for a `datalist` to be assigned to the text field so when the user begins typing suitable words will be offered from which they could select the correct city

Comment: it's just html. write the html to do look like you want, then you write php to generate html like that. And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: yes you are correct, i store the cities under students. is that an issue?

Comment: Not really an issue but not great db design. Usually if the db were normalised then you would have separate tables for things like countries,counties,cities etc and store the id in `students` for city or country etc

Comment: hey, please see my updated code and post please it might help

Comment: you'll not be able to send ALL the values using a standard submit button if that's what you mean by `i am trying to use the below code and send the below list to my database` - though you should have the selected value available in the POST array when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

As a rough example of how you could build the dropdown menu using data from your db this should give you the general idea perhaps.

```
/* store formatted menu options in temp array */
$html=array();

/* query db to find schools/cities */
$sql='select distinct `student_school` from `students` order by `student_school`';
$res=$mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

/* process recordset and store options */
if( $res ){
    while( $rs=mysqli_fetch_object( $res ) ){
        $html[]="<option value='{$rs->student_school}'>{$rs->student_school}";
    }
}

/* render menu */
echo "<select name='stu_city'>", implode( PHP_EOL, $html ), "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code by moving the if (isset($_POST)) above the html:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Student";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
}


$sql = "SELECT city_name FROM cities" ;
if ($conn->query ( $sql ) === TRUE) {
    $cities = ... // build the cities from the query result 
} else {
    $cities = '<option value="none">No cities found</option>' ;
}


if (isset ( $_POST ["submit"] )) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_school)
VALUES ('" . $_POST ["stu_name"] . "','" . $_POST ["stu_email"] . "','" . $_POST ["stu_city"] . "')";

    if ($conn->query ( $sql ) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error . "');</script>";
    }

    $conn->close ();
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>Insert data into database using mysqli</h1>
        <div id="login">
            <h2>Student's Form</h2>
            <hr />
            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>Student Name :</label> <input type="text" name="stu_name"
                    id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name" /><br />
                <br /> <label>Student Email :</label> <input type="email"
                    name="stu_email" id="email" required="required"
                    placeholder="john123@gmail.com" /><br />
                <br /> <label>Student City :</label> <select name="stu_city" multiple><?php echo $cities; ?>
                </select>><br />
                <br /> <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" /><br />
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Right side div -->


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,what do you mean by....    $cities = ... // build the cities from the query result ? I'm not sure what this means @Dominique Lorre

Comment: @dave Once you get the result from the SELECT query, you build `$cities = '<option>value="city1">city1</option><option>value="cit21">city2</option>';`  read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more help

Comment: i added your code but no luck. could you show me where this will fit into your code please

Comment: @dave What do you mean by no luck? You have an error?

Comment: yes i get an error saying:


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: stu_city in C:\wamp\www\view.php on line 26


Call Stack
#

Time

Memory

Function

Location

1 0.0006 137944 {main}( ) ...\view.php:0

Comment: @dave look at RamRaider's answer and update your question with your actual code.

Comment: hey, please see my updated code and post please it might help

Comment: @dave That's not the code I have shown you. And why are you using countries now?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Select tag: Lets say you hav a column in your database with Student City, like this, lets say the database field is called city

1. City 1
2. City 2
3. City 3

Step 1: Query the database and fetch all the Cities

```
    $sql = "SELECT city FROM table_name";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Then you come to your dropdown:

```
    <select name="stu_city" id="..." required>
      <?php
      while($cities = $conn->fetch_array($result){
        extract($cities);
        echo "<option value='...'>$city</option>";
      }
      ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi, i added the example code you gave me above into my code. however it didn't work. could you show me where to exactly insert this code of yours into mine please

Comment: Just follow the answers here, they will help you. . .

Comment: hey, please see my updated code and post please it might help

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code by moving the if (isset($_POST)) above the html:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Student";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
}


$sql = "SELECT city_name FROM cities" ;
$result = $conn->query ( $sql );


if (isset ( $_POST ["submit"] )) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_school)
VALUES ('" . $_POST ["stu_name"] . "','" . $_POST ["stu_email"] . "','" . $_POST ["stu_city"] . "')";

    if ($conn->query ( $sql ) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error . "');</script>";
    }

    $conn->close ();
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>Insert data into database using mysqli</h1>
        <div id="login">
            <h2>Student's Form</h2>
            <hr />
            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>Student Name :</label> <input type="text" name="stu_name"
                    id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name" /><br />
                <br /> <label>Student Email :</label> <input type="email"
                    name="stu_email" id="email" required="required"
                    placeholder="john123@gmail.com" /><br />
                <br /> <label>Student City :</label> <select name="stu_city" multiple> 
<?php
if ($result == TRUE) {
    while($cities = $conn->fetch_array($result)){
      extract($cities);
      echo "<option value=''>$city_name</option>";
 } 
}
else {
    echo "<option value='none'>No cities found</option>";
}

?>
                </select>><br />
                <br /> <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" /><br />
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Right side div -->


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when using your code i get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'submit' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\view.php on line 67

Comment: change line 67 to this     echo "<option value='none'>No cities found</option>";